# BMI calculator written in react.js class needs to be clicked twice on the submit button to mutate some of the this.state values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been working on a BMI calculator written in react.js class component, i found out that clicking on a submit button won't mutate some of the this.state values at first time, but the second click would mutate all values, i've read relevant questions in these links:

[Pass values to child component on click submit button - ReactJS, click twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46595130/pass-values-to-child-component-on-click-submit-button-reactjs-click-twice)

[ReactJS - Need to click twice to set State and run function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34800893/reactjs-need-to-click-twice-to-set-state-and-run-function)

but i couldn't figure it out how to add changes to my code.
Here is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
class App extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {fullName: '', weight: '', height: '', bmi: '', message: '', optimalWeight: ''};
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.calculateBMI = this.calculateBMI.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit =this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

handleChange(e){
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
}

calculateBMI(){
    let heightSquared = (this.state.height/100 * this.state.height/100);
    let bmi = this.state.weight / heightSquared;
    let low = Math.round(18.5 * heightSquared);
    let high = Math.round(24.99 * heightSquared);
    let message = "";
    if(bmi >= 18.5 && bmi <= 24.99){
        message = "You are in a healthy weight range";
    }
    else if(bmi >= 25 && bmi <= 29.9){
        message = "You are overweight";
    }
    else if(bmi >= 30){
        message="You are obese";
    }
    else if(bmi < 18.5){
        message="You are under weight";
    }
    this.setState({message: message});
    this.setState({optimalWeight: "Your suggested weight range is between "+low+ " - "+high});
    this.setState({bmi: Math.round(bmi * 100) / 100});
}


handleSubmit(e){
    this.calculateBMI();
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);

}

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="App">
                <div className="App-header">
                    <h2>BMI calculator</h2>
                </div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <label>
                        Please enter your name
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" name="fullName" value={this.state.fullName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    <label>
                        Enter your height in cm
                    </label>
                    <input type="number" name="height" value={this.state.height} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    <label>
                        Enter your weight in kg
                    </label>
                    <input type="number" name="weight" value={this.state.weight} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

update:

I also check the question [Using async setState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43370176/using-async-setstate) but my problem is not about updating in an async way but thanks to @LMulvey i did solve it by grouping **setState** and adding a **console.log** as callback function to it in **calculateBMI()**

Comment: You can set all the state properties you want in one `setState` call.

Comment: Also, setState is async, explaining why your console log is not up to date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using async setState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43370176/using-async-setstate)

Comment: @EmileBergeron i did group **setState** in **calculateBMI()** but the main solution to my problem is to add **console.log** to the last **setState** in **calculateBMI()** as @ LMulvey answered in below

Comment: My first comment was just a code review tip. The solution was in my second comment, which is already answered in my third comment.

Comment: Seeing your edit, it looks like you missed the point of the duplicate candidate. Even if you don't want to "update", `setState` is still async and the callback solution explained in the [_Using async setState_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43370176/using-async-setstate) is the same concept needed here. This is a common React mistake.

Comment: @EmileBergeron i saw your third comment but i couldn't solve my problem through that in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43370176/using-async-setstate , on the other hand my code is a simple react class component and not using redux

Comment: While the other asker is using a redux action function instead of `console.log`, the problem and solution is the same...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app is actually working just fine. The problem is that you're trying to log your state before `setState` has fully finished. If you instead attach your `console.log` as a callback to your final `setState` call, you'll see that it's working as intended.

```
this.setState({bmi: Math.round(bmi * 100) / 100}, () => console.log(this.state));
```

It's worth noting that you don't need one `setState` call for each property that you're updating and you can group them together like this, which would also be leading to your issue of race conditions here:

```
 this.setState({
    bmi: Math.round(bmi * 100) / 100,
    optimalWeight: "Your suggested weight range is between "+low+ " - "+high,
    message
}, () => console.log(this.state));
```

Comment: thanks , grouping **setState** and attaching **console.log** as a callback to final **setState** is awesome idea and it works fine